# Windows version of Unix touch command to modify a file's modification date from filename part

Tags: windows, bash, shell, batch-file, timestamp

I have this **bash script** that loops through the files in the current directory and extracts the **date part** from the **filename**, then uses (Unix) `touch` command to modify (or update) that file's **modification-date** (`mtime`) to this date.

**Filename example**

`Electric company name - bill - 2014-03-22.pdf`

**Bash script:**

I save this bash script as `_save_file_mtime_from_filename.sh` (add `chmod +x` to it) and put in the directory where I'd like to change the file's modification time. And then run it from the **command-line**.

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DIR=$(dirname $_)
cd $CURRENT_DIR

for f in *
do
    # Strip the file extension
    d=${f%.*}

    # Strip the last 10 characters
    d=${d:${#d}-10}

    # Check the format / mask
    if [[ $d = ????-??-?? ]] ; then
        # Strip the dash
        d=${d//-}

        # Run `touch` on the file with the extracted date format
        # and add `0000` to the file date
        touch -t ${d}0000 "$f"
    fi
done
```

Now I'm searching for a **Windows version of this script**

I've search the net (and Stackoverflow). Found some related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command and https://superuser.com/questions/251470/windows-recursive-touch-command/251507#251507

Does anyone have any idea for a **Windows version** using a `_save_file_mtime_from_filename.bat` executable version that does essentially the same thing?

*With a little tweaking and help of a (Mac) Automator action, saved as an 'application', you can even trigger this script in the Mac Finder from the right-mouse button (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5287944?start=15&tstart=0). Sweet!*

Comment: Why not just install cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), or install binaries from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) or [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @konsolebox. Just install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com), and you can run your script with no changes.

However, if you don't want to go that route, you should be able to install "coreutils" from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). Coreutils contains "touch", among other things. Writing a DOS batch file to emulate what you've written above might be a little painful, though. The part that looks tricky to me is `[[ $d = ????-??-?? ]]`. You'll have to do something creative to match that, perhaps using grep, which you can get from the same page. Now you're installing a couple things, and doing a lot of work, though. Installing Cygwin would be easier.